# Google Calendar API v3 with extJS Grid

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I am unable to get my grid to show JSON data from the Google Calendar API v3. The JSON data produces the expected results, but the grid shows nothing.

```
    var eventcalendar_portlet = function() {
calendarRenderer = function(value) {
    var tmpDate = "";
    var year = "";
    var month = "";
    var day = "";

    if (value != "") {
        // value will contain a datetime, strip off the time portion and make the date javascript friendly
        value = value.substring(0, 10);
        value = value.split('-');
        year = value[0];
        month = value[1];
        day = value[2];
        tmpDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
        // date is formated as mm/dd/yyyy.  format the return as abbreviated month name, ex. Jan, and date
        value = Ext.util.Format.date(tmpDate, 'M j');
    }
    return value;
}   

linkRenderer = function(value, metadata, record) {
    var linkVal = "";
    if (value != "") {
        linkVal = "<a href='" + record.data.link[0].href + "&ctz=America/Chicago' target='_blank'>" + value + "</a>";
        value = linkVal;
    }
    return value;
}
/*
 * Calculate year, month and day difference between two dates
 * This will be used to determine if a safety calendar event will happen within the next 7 days
 * and highlight that event if it falls within that timeframe
 */
getTimeBetween = function(from, until) {
    var past = from = '' ? new Date() : new Date(from);
    var future = until == '' ? new Date() : new Date(until);

    if (past >= future)
    {
        var tmp = past;
        past = future;
        future = tmp;
    }

    var between = [
        future.getFullYear() - past.getFullYear(),
        future.getMonth() - past.getMonth(),
        future.getDate() - past.getDate()
    ];

    if (between[2] < 0)
    {
        between[1]--;
        var ynum = future.getFullYear();

        var mlengths = [
            31,
            (ynum % 4 == 0 && ynum % 100 != 0 || ynum % 400 == 0) ? 29 : 28,
            31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
        ];

        var mnum = future.getMonth() - 1;
        if (mnum < 0) { mnum += 12; }

        between[2] += mlengths[mnum];
    }

    if (between[1] < 0)
    {
        between[0]--;
        between[1] += 12;
    }

    return between;
}

gridView = new Ext.grid.GridView({
    forceFit: true,
    getRowClass : function( row, index ) {
        var cls = '';
        var tmpDate = "";
        var year = "";
        var month = "";
        var day = "";
        var value = "";
        var data = row.data;
        if (data.when != "") {
            value = data.when;
            value = value.substring(0, 10);
            value = value.split('-');
            year = value[0];
            month = value[1];
            day = value[2];
            tmpDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
            var dateDiff = getTimeBetween(Date(), tmpDate);
            if (dateDiff[2] <= 7) {
                cls = 'highlightRow';
            }
        }
        return cls;
    }
});

eventCalendar = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store : new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url : 'calendar.cfm',
        root : 'items',
        fields : ['description',
                {name : 'when', mapping : 'start.date'}
                ]
    }),
    columns : [
        {dataIndex : 'when', width: 50, fixed : true, renderer : calendarRenderer, hideable : false, menuDisabled : true, sortable : false, resizable : false},
        {id: 'description', dataIndex : 'description', width: 200, hideable : false, menuDisabled : true, sortable : false, resizable : false, renderer : linkRenderer}
    ],
    autoExpandColumn : 'description',
    emptyText : 'There are no events scheduled within the next 30 days.',
    viewConfig : gridView,
    sm : new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect : true}),
    autoHeight : true,
    enableColumnMove : false,
    enableColumnResize : false,     
    bbar : new Ext.Toolbar({
        items:[
        'Highlighted items occur within the next 7 days.',
        '->',
        {
            text: 'View Calendar',
            handler: function() {
                window.open('http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=acmetrucking%40gmail.com&title=Acme%20Truck%20Line%20Calendar', '_blank');
            }
        }]
    })
});

eventCalendar.getStore().load();
portlet = new Ext.ux.Portlet({
    loadMask : true,
    title    : 'Acme Events Calendar',
    items    : eventCalendar,
    layout   : 'fit',
    tools: [{
        id: 'refresh',
        handler : function(e, t, p) {
            // e = event, t = pointer to tool button, p = pointer to panel
            eventCalendar.getStore().load();
        }
    }]
});
return {
    portlet : portlet
} 
}();
```

JSON being returned, cut short for brevity:

```
{
"kind" : "calendar#events",
"etag" : "\"1420315755244000\"",
"summary" : "Acme Truck",
"updated" : "2015-01-03T20:09:15.244Z",
"timeZone" : "America/Chicago",
"accessRole" : "reader",
"defaultReminders" : [],
"items" : [{
        "kind" : "calendar#event",
        "etag" : "\"2459950010742000\"",
        "id" : "fr3r8cch8vf02qi32nosftrq50_20150105",
        "status" : "confirmed",
        "htmlLink" : "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=ZnIzcjhjY2g4dmYwMnFpMzJub3NmdHJxNTBfMjAxNTAxMDUgYWNtZXRydWNraW5nQG0",
        "created" : "2006-12-08T16:04:58.000Z",
        "updated" : "2008-12-22T19:43:25.371Z",
        "summary" : "Expenses Due",
        "description" : "Expenses for the 16th thru the 31st due.",
        "creator" : {
            "email" : "acmetrucking@gmail.com",
            "displayName" : "Acme Truck",
            "self" : true
        },
        "organizer" : {
            "email" : "acmetrucking@gmail.com",
            "displayName" : "Acme Truck",
            "self" : true
        },
        "start" : {
            "date" : "2015-01-05"
        },
        "end" : {
            "date" : "2015-01-06"
        },
        "recurringEventId" : "fr3r8cch8vf02qi32nosftrq50",
        "originalStartTime" : {
            "date" : "2015-01-05"
        },
        "iCalUID" : "fr3r8cch8vf02qi32nosftrq50@google.com",
        "sequence" : 1
    }...}
]
```

}

ColdFusion code getting the JSON:

```
<cfhttp charset="us-ascii" url="https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/acmetrucking@gmail.com/events?singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&timeMin=#currentDateISO#&timeMax=#oneMonthISO#&key=xxxxxx"></cfhttp>



<cfoutput>#cfhttp.FileContent#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with the Google Maps Javascript API v3?  Did you include the wrong tag?

Comment: You don't show a) The data being returned b) Where the store is being loaded.

Comment: I checked via postman for the JSON.

Comment: The data looks fine, you're still missing b). Where are you telling the store to load?

Comment: Check it now. As near as I can figure the "eventCalendar" isn't loading the data. Do you think the root or fields are wrong somehow? This a retrofit for the new v3 API. We were using v2, and Google is no longer supporting it. It worked fine until that point.

Comment: And my extJS is very rusty.

Comment: This is the only section that has changed from Calendar API v2:`code`    root :     items',
   fields : ['description',
     {name : 'when', mapping : 'start.date'}
     ]
  }),
  columns : [
   {dataIndex : 'when', width: 50, fixed : true, renderer : calendarRenderer, hideable : false, menuDisabled : true, sortable : false, resizable : false},
   {id: 'description', dataIndex : 'description', width: 200, hideable : false, menuDisabled : true, sortable : false, resizable : false, renderer : linkRenderer}
  ],...